# Z18XER engine noise

Tags: engine

My vectra (1.8 VVT) started making a noise today that appears to be coming from the top of the engine.

i took the top cambelt cover off to see if anything looks like it was moving wrong, but all appears to be fine.

whilst it's louder at the cam end, than the other end, it is actually louder around the top of the rocket cover.

as a side note, I've been getting a lot of negative pressure lately, which can also be heard in the video when I lift the dip stick.

https://youtu.be/E17p_0BMgvM

any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I hear in the video, you have a major issue with crankcase pressure. It is likely caused by a bad/stuck PCV valve or a kinked/blocked PCV hose. This is allowing pressure to build up in the engine. Fix this first and see if it affects the other noise.

Also, it seems possible that the timing belt adjuster(s) or tensioners may be worn/broken. This can allow for "slapping" of the belt and followers.